# My StateButton state is not updating my view

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've trying to use StateButtons from Xamarin.CustomControls

I have 2 state buttons and I want them to work in a dichotodic way.

My view model is something like this:

```cs
        private bool _btn1Active { get; set; }

        public bool Btn1Active
        {
            get
            {
                return _btn1Active;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_btn1Active != value)
                {
                    _btn1Active = value;

                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Btn1Active");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _btn2Active { get; set; }

        public bool Btn2Active
        {
            get
            {
                return _btn2Active;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_btn2Active != value)
                {
                    _btn2Active = value;

                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Btn2Active");
                }
            }
        }
```

And I've binded state buttons like this:

```
Btn1.SetBinding(StateButton.IsPressedProperty, "Btn1Active");
Btn2.SetBinding(StateButton.IsPressedProperty, "Btn2Active");
```

And my button_clicked handler is:

```cs
private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myViewModel = BindingContext as BtnsViewModel;

            myViewModel.Btn1Active= !myViewModel.Btn1Active;
            myViewModel.Btn2Active= !myViewModel.Btn2Active;

        }
```

I've been debugging a long time and I saw every property notified and changed correctly but the view is not updating.

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo to test your code,it works properly.
The main code is as follows:

```
  public class TestModel2: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TestModel2()
    {
        Btn1Active = false;
        Btn2Active = false;
    }

    private bool _btn1Active;
    public bool Btn1Active
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _btn1Active, value); }
        get { return _btn1Active; }
    }

    private bool _btn2Active;
    public bool Btn2Active
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _btn2Active, value); }
        get { return _btn2Active; }
    }



    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

MyPage.xaml

```
<statebutton:StateButton Text="Rotate1" x:Name="Btn1" IsPressed="{Binding Btn1Active}"   RotateImages="true" ActiveTextColor="White" ActiveBackgroundColor="Teal" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Green" ActiveBorderColor="Black" LeftImage="arrowRight" ActiveLeftImage="arrowDown" RightImage="arrowRight" HeightRequest="60"  />
<statebutton:StateButton Text="Rotate2" x:Name="Btn2" IsPressed="{Binding Btn2Active}"   RotateImages="true" ActiveTextColor="White" ActiveBackgroundColor="Teal" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Green" ActiveBorderColor="Black" LeftImage="arrowRight" ActiveLeftImage="arrowDown" RightImage="arrowRight" HeightRequest="60"  />

<statebutton:StateButton Text="click(StateButton)" HeightRequest="60"  Clicked="StateButton_Clicked"/>
<Button  Text="click(Button)" HeightRequest="60" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

MyPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    TestModel2 myViewModel;

    public MyPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        myViewModel = new TestModel2();
        BindingContext = myViewModel;           
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myViewModel.Btn1Active = !myViewModel.Btn1Active;
        myViewModel.Btn2Active = !myViewModel.Btn2Active;
    }
    private void StateButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myViewModel.Btn1Active = !myViewModel.Btn1Active;
        myViewModel.Btn2Active = !myViewModel.Btn2Active;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I added a click event for a `StateButtons`, and it also works properly.
You can check the updated code.

The result is:
[image]

**Note:**

1.change the following code:

```
private bool _btn1Active { get; set; }
private bool _btn2Active { get; set; }
```

to :

```
 private bool _btn1Active;
 private bool _btn2Active;
```

2. the binding way you used is not correct, you can try this:

```
Btn1.SetBinding(StateButton.IsPressedProperty, new Binding("Btn1Active"));
Btn2.SetBinding(StateButton.IsPressedProperty, new Binding("Btn2Active"));
```

Or binding in `xaml`

```
<statebutton:StateButton Text="Rotate1" x:Name="Btn1" IsPressed="{Binding Btn1Active}"     />
<statebutton:StateButton Text="Rotate2" x:Name="Btn2" IsPressed="{Binding Btn2Active}"     />
```

3.pay attention to your `BindingContext`, you can do like this:

```
BtnsViewModel myViewModel;

myViewModel = new BtnsViewModel();
BindingContext = myViewModel;
```

For more details, you can check my demo code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My code still not working. I think that is a problem with the OnClicked default event of StateButtons, because I tested your solution with an extra button that manage the behaviour and it works. What should I do?

Comment: I  added a StateButton, and it also works properly. I have updated the answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your issue is with your Bindings.

Change it to

```
Btn1.SetBinding(StateButton.IsPressedProperty, new Binding("Btn1Active"));
Btn2.SetBinding(StateButton.IsPressedProperty, new Binding("Btn2Active"));
```

And it should work.

This is because the `BtnsViewModel` is not the `Context` of your Buttons but the `Context` of the whole Page where the buttons are.

One suggestion, your private fields do not need to be a Property. With this I meant

```
private bool _btn1Active { get; set; }
private bool _btn2Active { get; set; }
```

can be changed to

```
private bool _btn1Active;
private bool _btn2Active;
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. As I commented to @Jessie Zhang my code still not working. :c